# Scaling a LogPlot to better show its minimum

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I've got a function. I want to scale the X-axis in a weird way. I want value of `h = 10^-4` to appear in the middle of X-axis.

In my plot, shown below, we can't see that function is decreasing. How can I achieve my goal?

Function `fn3` is deacreasing in interval `0 < h < 10^-4` and increasing in the interval `10^-4 < h <= 1`.

[image]

Comment: Why can't you just adjust the plot range with `PlotRange`? Also, it's better if you write you code instead of pasting the image. Add the values of parameters for which you want to plot the function.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it ? I just started with mathematica.

Comment: Link to the documentation: [PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html). As an additional option to your plot command add (for example) `PlotRange->{{10^-5,10^-3}, {0, 0.1} }`. You have to try with different plot ranges to get what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get the kind of plot you want with `LogLogPlot`. Like so:

```
fn3[h_, ϵ_] := (2 ϵ/h + h/2) Cos[1]
With[{ϵ = 10^-8/4}, LogLogPlot[fn3[h, ϵ], {h, 10^-10, 10}]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Comments

1. It would have been helpful if you had given the value of `ϵ` which minimizes your function at `h = 10^-4`. It would have saved me the effort of computing it.
2. Your function `fn3` can be written in the simpler way I show in this answer.

Comment: The value you give for `epsilon` is just `Solve[fun3'[10^-4] == 0, epsilon][[1]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon. That'a basically what I did. However, the OP must have had the value of `ϵ` at hand and should have provided it.

Answer (score 0):

Amplifying on m_goldberg's answer

```
Clear[fun3, h]
```

Since

```
Cos[1.]

(* 0.540302 *)
```

use of `Abs` is unnecessary. Or just use [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) rather than [`SetDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) in defining `fun3`

```
fun3[h_] = (2*epsilon*Abs[Cos[1]]/h) + (h*Abs[Cos[1]]/2) // Simplify

(* ((4 epsilon + h^2) Cos[1])/(2 h) *)
```

When the minimum occurs, the derivative is zero. The value of `epsilon` for `fun3` to have a minimum at `10^-4` is given by

```
eps = Solve[fun3'[10^-4] == 0, epsilon][[1]]

(* {epsilon -> 1/400000000} *)
```

The minimum is

```
fun3[10^-4] /. eps

(* Cos[1]/10000 *)

% // N

(* 0.0000540302 *)
```

The `PlotRange` for a symmetric [`LogLogPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html) is

```
{hmin, hmax} = h /. Solve[(fun3[h] == fun3[1]) /. eps, h] // Sort

(* {1/100000000, 1} *)
```

Using these values

```
p1 = LogLogPlot[fun3[h] /. eps, {h, hmin, hmax}]
```

[image]